# How to get single-digit Days in a certain format in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am using the following `Visual Basic` code to get the `Day` from a `Date`:

```
Dim thisDate As Date
Dim thisDay As 
thisDate = Today
thisDay = Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Day(thisDate)
```

When the day is a single digit such as today (November 1st) then
`thisDay` returns `1`.
Is there a way to adjust this so that single-digit days are returned as such `01, 02, 03,...`, instead of `1, 2, 3,...`?
Thank you!

Comment: That code looks like vb.net to me which I can't answer because it's a different language to VB6. Please remove the vb6 tag!

Comment: I removed it. It seems like someone edited my question and added that tag in.

Comment: Ok thanks. You have your answer now from a .net user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the date(using Now) to a string and then manipulate the string accordingly.

Example:

```
 Dim twodigitdate As String
 twodigitdate = Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
 twodigitdate = Mid(twodigitdate, 1, 2)
 MsgBox(twodigitdate)
```

or you can just use this one line code :-

```
dim twodigitdate as string = Now.ToString("dd")
```